# EMI suppression in battery system

Tags: batteries, emc, emi-filtering, feedthrought-capacitor

As I'm updating my battery-based PCB that drives 4x 8' conductors (all at DC), I'm trying to improve my chances of passing the FCC Part 15 for unintentional radiation from those long conductors. My fastest digital clock is only 4MHz. The battery is just a single cell AA Li-ion at 3.7V nominal and is wirelessly charged @ about 120kHz. There are a couple of switching converters on-board: a boost @ 1.2MHz and a buck @ 570kHz.

However, I have no experience with EMI suppression in battery systems.

My first thought was to use SMT feedthrough capacitors, but I recall a fellow EE's comment that they need an earth ground to work, which I don't have available. Is this true and would ferrite beads or simple capacitive decoupling work better?

I also recall an EMC test engineer (owned a small RF emissions test lab) saying that he never saw a battery product fail unintentional emissions.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe some generic advice is to keep high-frequency loops as small as possible. DC doesn't matter. AC goes through capacitors, DC doesn't. This is the true purpose of decoupling capacitors: high frequencies go through the capacitor. Don't make them take the long way through a really long wire.

Comment: Welcome! Post schematic and layout.